# Magento 2 Authorize.net Direct Post Method error - Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller

Tags: php, magento, magento2, authorize.net

In Magento 2.2.5 I have enabled the authorize.net Direct Post Method in Sandbox mode, while trying to make the payment at checkout page it's showing error message `Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller.`

I checked the console to troubleshoot and found that below message showing in Request URL: `https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll`

```
The reporting of this transaction to the Merchant has timed out. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.       

This transaction has been approved.

It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.
```

I did lots of research and found that it may occur due the many reasons, I applied all the fixes but still have the same problem.

**Below are the key points:**

Authorize.net Sandbox URLs:

Gateway URL: `https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll`

Transaction Details URL: `https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api`

Test Mode: `NO`

SSL: `enabled`

MD5 Hash: `Yes, Less than 10 character long.`

Debug Log:

```
    main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'x_version' => '3.1',
    'x_delim_data' => 'FALSE',
    'x_relay_response' => 'TRUE',
    'x_test_request' => 'FALSE',
    'x_login' => '****',
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_relay_url' => 'https://mydomain/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response',
    'x_type' => 'AUTH_CAPTURE',
    'x_fp_sequence' => '43',
    'x_invoice_num' => '000000030',
    'x_amount' => 50.0,
    'x_currency_code' => 'USD',
    'x_tax' => '0.00',
    'x_freight' => '5.00',
    'x_first_name' => 'Demo',
    'x_last_name' => 'Buyer1',
    'x_company' => 'Demo',
    'x_address' => 'New Street 33',
    'x_city' => 'California',
    'x_state' => 'California',
    'x_zip' => '56005',
    'x_country' => 'US',
    'x_phone' => '0123456789',
    'x_fax' => '',
    'x_cust_id' => '',
    'x_customer_ip' => '103.15.66.130',
    'x_customer_tax_id' => '',
    'x_email' => 'myemailaddresss',
    'x_email_customer' => '0',
    'x_merchant_email' => '',
    'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'Demo',
    'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'Buyer1',
    'x_ship_to_company' => 'Demo',
    'x_ship_to_address' => 'New Street 33',
    'x_ship_to_city' => 'California',
    'x_ship_to_state' => 'California',
    'x_ship_to_zip' => '56005',
    'x_ship_to_country' => 'US',
    'x_po_num' => '',
    'x_fp_timestamp' => 1538807586,
    'x_fp_hash' => '16bf75c140a4ca76a6dcf3dc82a5c4bf',
  ),
)
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: If you're still having issues with this, a couple of suggestions.  First, the error message occurs when the gateway cannot POST back to the 'x_relay_url' configured.  It must be publicly available, on port 80/443 and have a valid certificate if HTTPS.

I should also point out that the integration method used by this module is deprecated.  Instead, I would suggest using our our new magento extension at https://marketplace.magento.com/authorizenet-magento-module-authorizenet.html

Comment: @rhldr thanks for the comment, I have been fixed this issue but updated here. Yes, you are also on the right track, my dev site had the IP restriction applied that's why not available to the outside world and authorize.net not able to post on x_relay_url.

Answer (score 1):

I have been found the problem and fixed the issue, it was a silly mistake. Actually, my dev site had the IP restriction applied, hence why it was not available to the outside world and authorize.net not able to post on x_relay_url.

Hope this help someone to save their time in this kind of situations.

Thank You